# How to make the terminal font look like notepad's?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, text-editor

The terminal font of Visual Studio 2013 text editor looks nothing like the terminal font of notepad (OS is Windows 8.1 64 bit). It's an annoyance to me, especially when coding in C; nearly superscripted (and miniature sized) star feels out of place. Funny thing is, on VS2013 text editor, Terminal and FixedSys are exactly the same thing (which is neither Terminal nor FixedSys of notepad).

Is there way to take my Terminal font back?

(Consolas is sort of okay, but it has the same issue of the elevated star character).

Comment: Notepad (at least in Win7 on my machine) uses Lucida Console, Regular, 10. Don't know if that will help, but I'll pass it along anyway.

Comment: Thanks Ken, but Lucida Console also suffers the same elevated star (*) problem as Terminal does on VS2013. Terninal font on notepad looks perfect, but I cannot get the same Terminal font on VS2013 text editor.

Comment: You cannot use Terminal or FixedSys in VS, they are device fonts and the font mapper substitutes them.  You'll get Courier New instead.  I don't know of any fixed-pitch TrueType or OpenType font that will make you happy.  You'll get used to it.

Comment: Ok Hans, so you're saying that the good old days of Visual Studio 2003 are gone, where I could use both Terminal and FixedSys as is in the text editor. This is sad news indeed.

Comment: But wait a moment, why can't I use them in VS text editor, but I can in Notepad?